# Setting the CRS for non-geographical svg map

Tags: leaflet

I'm trying to show a custom non-geographical map with **CRS.simple** as explained [here](https://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html):

> In a CRS.Simple, one horizontal map unit is mapped to one horizontal
> pixel, and idem with vertical

However, I wish to use an SVG vector image as an overlay, but I don't get how the map unit is decided in this case, since the vector images don't really have a resolution?

Also, how could set the CRS origin's location to a specific point?

Thanks for helping

Comment: The CRS units remain the same - what shall change is the bounds of your `L.SVGOverlay`.

Comment: @IvanSanchez I get the idea when it is a raster, I would just match the bounds and the picture resolution. But a SVG drawing does not have intrinsic width and height, does it?

Comment: Yes it does. SVG does have an internal arbitrary coordinate system AFAIK. See e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Content_type#length , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGLength